# Selecting a column with two different conditions joined on two different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, relational-database

For the code below I need to select the column `[Score Value]` from the table `#ScoreTemp`, but I need to select it as two different columns based on the condition that another column `[Score]` is equal to the string `'Fico'` for one column, and `'Revbal'` for another column. I'm unsure how to do this when values for both conditions exist in one table. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
SELECT a.CBRRequestDate AS UpdateDate
    ,b.[Score Value] AS Fico
    ,c.[Score Value] AS Revbal
    ,NULL AS TUGroup
    ,a.Vision_Practitioner_Id__c AS PID
FROM [SFOnPrem].[dbo].[Contact] a
LEFT JOIN #ScoreTemp d ON a.Id = d.Guarantor__c
LEFT JOIN #ScoreTemp b ON a.Id = b.Guarantor__c
    AND b.Score = 'Fico'
LEFT JOIN #ScoreTemp c ON a.Id = c.Guarantor__c
    AND c.Score = 'Revbal'
```

Comment: please show some sample data and the expected result. It is easier to understand your requirement from the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be fine.  But if you have missing values, then use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT c.CBRRequestDate AS UpdateDate,
       stf.[Score Value] AS Fico,
       str.[Score Value] AS Revbal,
       NULL AS TUGroup,
       c.Vision_Practitioner_Id__c AS PID
FROM [SFOnPrem].[dbo].[Contact] c LEFT JOIN
     #ScoreTemp stf
     ON a.Id = stf.Guarantor__c AND
        stf.Score = 'Fico' LEFT JOIN
     #ScoreTemp str
     ON a.Id = str.Guarantor__c AND
        str.Score = 'Revbal';
```

Note that I fixed the table aliases so they are no longer meaningless letters, but rather abbreviations for the table names.  I also changed the first column so it comes from `contact` -- that seems logic to me in this context, but it might not be correct.